# Arduino Serial.println prints only the first character correctly

Tags: c#, arduino

I have the following Arduino sketch:

```
int hygrometer = A3;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  int value = analogRead(hygrometer);    
  value = constrain(value,400,1023);  
  value = map(value,400,1023,100,0);  
  Serial.println(value);
  delay(2000);
}
```

However, on the other side of the serial communication (a .NET Core application hosted on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian), I get some weird results, as only the 1st character is displayed correctly, the rest being just random bytes. Moreover, if I run the Serial Monitor without having the application listening to serial running, the values are displayed correctly. However, in the moment I start the application, the Serial Monitor displays the same thing.

This is the .NET Core code for initializing the serial communication:

```
SerialDevice serial = new SerialDevice(port1, BaudRate.B9600);

serial.Parity = Parity.None;
serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serial.DataBits = 8;
serial.Handshake = Handshake.None;

serial.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;

if (serial != null && serial.IsOpen)
    serial.Close();

serial.Open();
```

Any idea on what's happening?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure that you can have multiple listeners, the app and the serial monitor on the serial communication. The issue could be a baud-rate issue or a overflow of a variable, don't think the latter is the case. But keep that in mind. Had some communication issues dealing with Arduino BT to C#.

Comment: Found this on the Arduino forum: Arduino isn't RS232, its serial using digital pins, it doesn't use handshaking. I've connected more than one Arduino listening to one transmitting just by hooking up the RX and gnd lines.  Usually you can't use more than one on RS232 because the handshaking (hard or soft) gets confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the reading in while-loop maybe you could capture the rest of the bits. 
Try this:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static SerialPort _serialPort;
        public static void Main()
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM4";  //Set your board COM
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort.Open();
            while (true)
            {
                string a = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                Thread.Sleep(200); // !!! Not sure if this is necessary !!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```